# Is there any function to polyline coordinates from react leaflet routing machine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I completely new to react and I'm assigned with a project to calculate toll between two locations,I'm using leaflet to render map and toll guru to calculate total amount. I looking to fetch coordinates of polyline which I've drawn using leaflet routing machine.

I tried to use getRoute as suggested by Google but it doesn't seems to work